# Show edit contact in Contact UI

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I'm using this to show contact detail and it has option to edit contact:

```
let toFetch = [CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys()]
let cnContact = try contactStore!.unifiedContact(withIdentifier: contanctIdentifier, keysToFetch: toFetch)

let contactsViewController = CNContactViewController(for: cnContact)
contactsViewController.delegate = self
contactsViewController.allowsEditing = true
```

But I want to show edit screen without showing contact detail.

Answer (score 1):

just change CNContactViewController(for: cnContact) to

let cvc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact) it will work

```
let contactsViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: cnContact)
contactsViewController.delegate = self
contactsViewController.allowsEditing = true
```